# How to use PL/SQL to display many tuples from a database?

Tags: oracle, plsql, timestamp, sqlplus

I am trying to use PL/SQL to display data from two tables where the durations of the flight are between some input range. I am having trouble figuring out where I am going wrong since I am new to this. Flights.arrives and Flights.depart data members are timestamps which may be my biggest issue.

**problem1.sql**

```
SET serveroutput ON

accept leftLimit prompt "Enter minimum time(min): ";
accept rightLimit prompt "Enter maximum time(min): ";

DECLARE
    flightNo varchar2(20);
    fromAirport varchar2(20);
    toAirport varchar2(20);
    duration varchar2(20);

CURSOR myTuplesCursor IS 
    SELECT Flights.flightNo, 
            Flights.fromAirport, 
            Flights.toAirport, 
            Flights.arrives - Flights.depart 
    FROM Aircraft, Flights 
    WHERE Aircraft.airplaneID = Flights.airplaneID 
    AND (Flights.arrives - Flights.depart)
        BETWEEN &leftLimit AND &rightLimit;

BEGIN
    OPEN myTuplesCursor; -- run the query

    LOOP
        -- Get tuples from data
        FETCH myTuplesCursor INTO flightNo, fromAirport, toAirport, duration ;
        EXIT WHEN myTuplesCursor%NOTFOUND;

        -- Display tuples of data
        dbms_output.put_line('Flight #: ' || flightNo );
        dbms_output.put_line('From: ' || fromAirport );
        dbms_output.put_line('To: ' || toAirport );
        dbms_output.put_line('Duration: ' || duration );
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE myTuplesCursor; -- end the query
END;
/
```

**Output**

```
SQL> @problem1
Enter minimum time(min): '+000000000 01:15:00.000000'
Enter maximum time(min): '+000000000 03:15:00.000000'
old 16:                 BETWEEN &leftLimit AND &rightLimit;
new 16:                 BETWEEN +000000000 01:15:00.000000 AND +000000000 03:15:00.000000;
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 22
```

Comment: And I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64 bit Production.

Comment: I do not have an environment to test at the moment but would suspect that wrapping &leftLimit and &rightLimit in a to_timestamp would resolve the issue.  when accepting the parameters they will be strings so it will be reading 01:15 as the string 01 then a bind variable of :15.

Comment: While you may need to convert the  entered strings to actual intervals, it's not clear to me what are the datatypes of `Flights.arrives` & `Flights.depart`  and why are you subtracting them for comparing it with your intervals?

Comment: @KaushikNayak the question states that the arrives and departs are timestamps (last sentence of the initial paragraph)

Comment: @ShaunPeterson what would the second parameter be to_timestamp(&leftLimit, ??); I haven't added this in yet but I fixed something else and I am not having the binding error now, instead I have a numeric value error. I updated the original post's code and output.

Comment: The second parameter is the format that to_timestamp can expect your string in.  However @XING has examples in his excellent answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the obvious error I see here is your `Cursor` declaration. You must not use `INTO` clause while declaring an explicit cursor. Apart, as @Kaushik mention, it's not clear what are the datatypes of `Flights.arrives` & `Flights.depart`, it would be hard to answer your query. Modify your code as below and try:

```
   CURSOR myTuplesCursor IS 
    SELECT Flights.flightNo, 
            Flights.fromAirport, 
            Flights.toAirport, 
            Flights.arrives - Flights.depart 
    --<-- You should not use into clause while using a cursor. Remove it.
    --INTO flightNo, fromAirport, toAirport, duration  FROM Aircraft, Flights 
    WHERE Aircraft.airplaneID = Flights.airplaneID 
    AND (Flights.arrives - Flights.depart) BETWEEN &leftLimit AND &rightLimit;
```

**EDIT:**

> The datatypes of Flights.arrives and Flights.depart are timestamps,
>   and I am trying to subtract the depart from arrives to figure the
>   duration of the flight.

In general if you want to `subtract` two `timestamps` then can be done as shown.

```
SQL> select TO_TIMESTAMP('03:15:00.000000', 'HH24:MI:SS.FF') - TO_TIMESTAMP('01:15:00.000000', 'HH24
:MI:SS.FF') tp from dual;

TP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000000 02:00:00.000000000
```

Now since your column is already `timestamp` no need to cast it. You can use the passed values in `between` clause as shown.

```
SELECT 1
FROM
  (SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('03:15:00.000000', 'HH24:MI:SS.FF') - TO_TIMESTAMP('01:15:00.000000', 'HH24:MI:SS.FF') tp
  FROM dual
  )
WHERE tp BETWEEN '+000000000 01:15:00.000000' AND '+000000000 03:15:00.000000' ;
```

Now since you now know how to subtract two timestamps in your block, you need to declare a variable to hold your result in block.

I see you try to hold the result of subtraction in variable `duration varchar2(20);` which is correct but string `buffer` appears too short and hence you face the error. You must change it to `duration varchar2(100);` for safer side. See below:

You would face error like shown below:

```
DECLARE
  duration VARCHAR2(20);  
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('03:15:00.000000', 'HH24:MI:SS.FF') - TO_TIMESTAMP('01:15:00.000000', 'HH24:MI:SS.FF') tp
  INTO duration
  FROM dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('Duration: ' || duration );
END;
```

Error:

```
Error report:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 4
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

When you change the variable size to `100`,Block will complete successfully as shown:

```
DECLARE
  duration VARCHAR2(100);  
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('03:15:00.000000', 'HH24:MI:SS.FF') - TO_TIMESTAMP('01:15:00.000000', 'HH24:MI:SS.FF') tp
  INTO duration
  FROM dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('Duration: ' || duration );
END;
```

Output:

```
Duration: +000000000 02:00:00.000000000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: The datatypes of Flights.arrives and Flights.depart are timestamps, and I am trying to subtract the depart from arrives to figure the duration of the flight. Thank you, I did remove the into clause. Now I am getting a different error.

Comment: DECLARE * ERROR at line 1: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error ORA-06512: at line 22